# "Dumped them Ceremoniously"- Is this an oxymoron? In a physical sense, like, dumping a bunch of leaves. Or Flowers? Along those lines

Tags: phrases, oxymoron

Is the phrase **Dumped them Ceremoniously** an oxymoron? Is it over the "oxymoron" word limit?

I hit upon this phrase when I was trying to write in a humorous vein about someone throwing something, albeit something that was costly so it had to be thrown with care. Here, the word is being used to describe a physical action, i.e. dumping a few rods. Does the same principle of **"dumping"** a person apply to, you know, dumping rods?

Note: If it is NOT an oxymoron, I'm going to delete the tag pronto.

Comment: Any film which qualifies as a romantic comedy will have at least one scene, often in the 2nd act, where the primarily love interest *ceremoniously dumps* the protagonist (that is, with a lot of drama and circumstance, making a real scene of it!. So, no, IMO the term is not an oxymoron, and can describe certain interactions in a literal way.

Comment: Does it apply to actually physically throwing things? Trampoline support rods for example? And uhh..not to sound pushy, but could you like, post it as an answer? Really don't like leaving an answered question officially "unanswered"

Comment: You can also say: He unceremoniously dumped her with a text message.

Comment: Uhhh....I was kinda asking about the antonym. "Ceremoniously", not "unceremoniously"

Comment: It seems to me that one might ceremoniously dump an object. For example as a way of telling the protagonist to get lost, his girlfriend might take the flowers he has bought, open the bin, hold them for a moment a few feet above the bin while looking him in the eye, and then drop the flowers in the bin. That would be dumping them ceremoniously.

Comment: If you are dumping something then you are getting rid of it with no intention of retrieving it, so the idea of "throwing it with care" because it is costly does not make sense in this  context. In the "Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy" Slartibartfast carelessly throws an award to one side, "but no so carelessly that it didn't land on something soft". However I can't think of a good phrase to describe this action.

Comment: "Ceremoniously" simply means "with great ceremony" -- with an accompanying "performance" or "ritual".  Certainly you can accomplish virtually any task that way, if that is what you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ceremonious dumping appears to be much less common than unceremonious dumping, if we are to judge from this Ngram chart for "ceremoniously dumped" (blue line) versus "unceremoniously dumped" (red line) for the period 1850–2005:

[image]

Examples of "unceremoniously dumped" go back to the nineteenth century. From "[The Merz System of Garbage Utilization in Four American Cities](https://books.google.com/books?id=Yi1KAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA356&dq=%22unceremoniously+dumped%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjni8PZuqXMAhUB3mMKHa1VAdIQ6AEINzAF#v=onepage&q=%22unceremoniously%20dumped%22&f=false)," in *Engineering News* (November 1, 1894):

> The Merz system was introduced in Buffalo [New York] in the fall of 1888 by a Mr. Baynes, who was then under contract to dispose of the city's garbage. Prior to this various methods of disposal had been tried. Some garbage had been used by farmers as a fertilizer and some had been **unceremoniously dumped** into the Niagara River. This latter practice gave rise to complaints from the towns below drawing water supplies from the river and had to be stopped.

And in the slang sense of "gotten rid of as if [the person] were garbage," we have instances from as far back as Robert Smith, [*Baseball: A Historical Narrative of the Game, the Men Who Have Played It, and Its Place in American Life*](https://books.google.com/books?id=L3W1AAAAIAAJ&q=%22unceremoniously+dumped%22&dq=%22unceremoniously+dumped%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXqMqFvaXMAhUG9mMKHfNGATgQ6AEINjAG) (1947) [combined snippets]:

> John McGraw had dropped two of his players at the end of the 1919 season. Nobody had been indicted; but McGraw could recognize a stink when he smelled it and, rough and tough as he was, eager as he was to win "by any means," he was never a man to countenance any crooked work. So his high-priced first baseman, the sardonic Hal Chase, and his expensive third baseman, Heinie Zimmerman, had been **unceremoniously dumped**. Why they were dumped now came out.

The pedigree of "ceremoniously dumped" is somewhat shorter, but Google Books finds matches going back to the late 1920s. From [*The American Medical Association Bulletin*](https://books.google.com/books?id=W5hXAAAAMAAJ&q=%22ceremoniously+dumped%22&dq=%22ceremoniously+dumped%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYuKP55KXMAhVX8GMKHaUNBwcQ6AEILDAD), volumes 20–22 (1925–1927[?]):

> He was a friend, a counsellor, a part of the simple lives of his patients, unstirred as they are now by jazz, heartrending unfickle movies, automobiles and petting parties. Often his reward was a sack of spuds **ceremoniously dumped** into the wagon box, or a joint of ham or side of bacon.

And from Jim Tully, [*Blood on the Moon*](https://books.google.com/books?id=PKXPAAAAMAAJ&q=%22ceremoniously+dumped%22&dq=%22ceremoniously+dumped%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj44fK6g6bMAhUP7mMKHezMBrkQ6AEIHTAA) (1931):

> One compartment contained blank slips, the other contained the questions, when the assistants returned to the stage. A twist of the handle and the blank slips were **ceremoniously dumped** upon the table in the full glare of lights.

The use of "ceremoniously dumped" in the sense of jettisoning a person, with accompanying pomp and circumstance, is newer still. The earliest arguable match of that usage in Google Books is from Mike Clifford, [*The Harmony Illustrated Encyclopedia of Rock*](https://books.google.com/books?id=zGsZAQAAIAAJ&q=%22Founded+the+NEMS+agency,+and+subsequently%22&dq=%22Founded+the+NEMS+agency,+and+subsequently%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqnNri6aXMAhVD1mMKHX09A3gQ6AEIHzAA) (1986) [combined snippets]:

> Founded the NEMS agency, and subsequently bought London West End theatre the Savile, where he promoted a series of Established reputation with Columbia Records during '60s and '70s with phenomenal AOR, MOR roster, including Simon & Garfunkel, Barbra Streisand, Santana, Byrds, Chicago (recently **ceremoniously dumped** by label), Brian Epstein-Don Kirshner rock concerts in mid-'60s.

More-recent written instances include references to a Venezuelan banker "[ceremoniously dumped](https://books.google.com/books?id=6O2zAAAAIAAJ&q=%22ceremoniously+dumped%22&dq=%22ceremoniously+dumped%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwirhMXb7aXMAhVW7GMKHT7QAmw4ChDoAQgjMAI)" by his bank (January 5, 1994) [snippet not visible in window], a TV news reporter "[ceremoniously dumped by CBS](https://books.google.com/books?id=XK0rAAAAYAAJ&q=%22ceremoniously+dumped%22&dq=%22ceremoniously+dumped%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxq4z16qXMAhUX22MKHeoVDxw4ChDoAQgbMAA)" (1996), a government administrator "[ceremoniously dumped](https://books.google.com/books?id=uu6UAAAAMAAJ&q=%22ceremoniously+dumped%22&dq=%22ceremoniously+dumped%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7xuTZ6qXMAhVB8mMKHfYeDJgQ6AEISTAJ)" by President Andrew Johnson (1996), and an administartion official "[ceremoniously dumped by [Bill] Clinton](https://books.google.com/books?id=472xKhTK-z0C&q=%22ceremoniously+dumped%22&dq=%22ceremoniously+dumped%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxq4z16qXMAhUX22MKHeoVDxw4ChDoAQg0MAY)" (1997). Perhaps more on point to the OP's example of "dumping a few rods" is this description in [*The SAR Magazine*](https://books.google.com/books?id=jQkRAQAAMAAJ&q=%22ceremoniously+dumped%22&dq=%22ceremoniously+dumped%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLzNjZ76XMAhVN6GMKHSykBFYQ6AEIHTAA) (1989) [combined snippets]:

> The year following the "Boston Tea Party", New York City had its own tea party on April 22, 1774. Eighteen chests of tea were found hidden in a merchant vessel and were **ceremoniously dumped** into New York harbor by the New York Sons of Liberty. Also, the tea ship *Nancy*, which had arrived at the same time, was forced to return to England with its cargo of British tea.

Dumping can be done ceremoniously, unceremoniously, or with a slight nod toward ceremony. In any case, there is no reason to view "dumped them ceremoniously" as being inherently oxymoronic, since dumping can be formal or informal, carefully planned or spontaneous.